# 2 annoying exceptions in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter, pytube

Good evening. I've been learning python and started to build some projects using libraries, like pytube. Recently, I've been trying to build a downloader using a user-friendly interface: Tkinter, but I keep getting these 2 errors, 1 when I click the Download button to download a single music and another when I click to download a playlist.
I reviewed my code a bunch of times but couldn't find the problem.

This is the error for the single music:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\Desktop\Python files\denovo.py", line 39, in Download
    yt = YouTube(Youtube_link)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.video_id = extract.video_id(url)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 133, in video_id
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line 129, in regex_search
    raise RegexMatchError(caller="regex_search", pattern=pattern)
pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError: regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*
```

This is the error for playlist download

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\Desktop\Python files\denovo.py", line 66, in Download2
    directory = f'{pl.title}'
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 351, in title
    return self.sidebar_info[0]['playlistSidebarPrimaryInfoRenderer'][
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 93, in sidebar_info
    self._sidebar_info = self.initial_data['sidebar'][
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 81, in initial_data
    self._initial_data = extract.initial_data(self.html)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 58, in html
    self._html = request.get(self.playlist_url)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 48, in playlist_url
    return f"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={self.playlist_id}"
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py", line 39, in playlist_id
    self._playlist_id = extract.playlist_id(self._input_url)
  File "C:\Users\kelle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py", line 151, in playlist_id
    return parse_qs(parsed.query)['list'][0]
KeyError: 'list'
```

This is my current code

```
from pytube import YouTube, Playlist
import os, os.path
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *


def window1():
    intro = Label(root1, text = "Welcome", font=( "Times New Roman", 14))
    intro.grid(row= 1, column = 1)
    intro2 = Label (root1, text = "Music or Playlist", font=("Times New Roman", 14))
    intro2.grid(row=2, column=1)

    buttonm= Button(root1, text= "Music", command= music, width= 20, font= ("Times New Roman", 12))
    buttonm.grid(row= 3, column= 1)

    buttonp= Button (root1, text= "Playlist", command=playlist, width=20, font= ("Times New Roman", 12))
    buttonp.grid(row=4, column=1)

def music():
    root2 = tk.Tk()
    root1.destroy()

    root2.title("Downloader")

    linkmusic = Label(root2, text="Link", font=("Times New Roman", 12))
    linkmusic.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    root2.linkText = Entry(root2, width=50, textvariable=linkvideo)
    root2.linkText.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, columnspan=2)

    buttondownload = Button(root2, text="Download ", command=Download, width=20, font=("Times New Roman", 12))
    buttondownload.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=3, pady=3)


def Download():
    folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    Youtube_link = linkvideo.get()

    yt = YouTube(Youtube_link)
    print(yt.title)
    titulo = yt.title
    ys = yt.streams.get_by_itag(251)
    print(ys)
    ys.download(folder)

    messagebox.showinfo("Saved")

def playlist():
    root3 = tk.Tk()
    root1.destroy()

    root3.title("Downloader")
    linkplaylist = Label(root3, text="Link", font=("Times New Roman", 12))
    linkplaylist.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
    root3.linkText = Entry(root3, width=50, textvariable=linkplay)
    root3.linkText.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, columnspan=2)

    button2download = Button(root3, text="Download ", command=Download2, width=20, font=("Times New Roman", 12))
    button2download.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=3, pady=3)

def Download2():
    folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    Youtubeplaylist = linkplay.get()
    pl= Playlist(Youtubeplaylist)

    directory = f'{pl.title}'
    path = os.path.join(folder, directory)
    os.mkdir(path)

    for video in pl.videos:
        video.streams.get_by_itag(251).download()

    files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder, "*.mp3"))
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            shutil.move(file, path)

    messagebox.showinfo("Saved")


root1 = tk.Tk()
root1.geometry("600x400")
root1.title("Downloader")
linkvideo = StringVar()
linkplay= StringVar()
window1()
root1.mainloop()
```

I hope someone can help me to fix these problems.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whatever the return value for `parse_qs(parsed.query)` is, it does not have a `'list'` key - use a debugger to see what the value is and adjust accordingly. Similarly, the regex you're using just doesn't match the string you're running it against - use a debugger to see what the value of the string actually is, and fix the regex (or whatever is creating the string)

Comment: The exceptions are not due to `tkinter`, it is the error from `pytube`, and it looks like a common error, so google it up

Comment: I already did it. It's strange because when I do a single project (i.e. to download only music or only playlist) these errors don't show up. 
I'll stick with these two until I learn more about pytube.
Thanks for the help, guys!